# Unity Highscore using PlayerPrefs not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is probably an EXTREMELY simple solution and problem, but I've been racking my brain for it. Every time I test this in unity, if I get a lower score than the high score, the High score changes regardless. Here is my code. Please tell me if you need more.

Script 1:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class CheckConeDeath : MonoBehaviour {
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision CollisionInfo){
        if(CollisionInfo.collider.tag=="Cone"){
            movement.enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
            Invoke ("EndGame", 1.5f);
        }
    }
    void EndGame(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("finalScore", Mathf.RoundToInt(FindObjectOfType<DistanceScore>().plrz));
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();

        Debug.Log (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore"));
        SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Script 2:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class finalscore : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text text;

    public Text highscore;
    void Start(){
        Debug.Log (Mathf.Round (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("finalScore")));
        Debug.Log (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("hs", 0));
        Debug.Log (Mathf.Round (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("finalScore")) > PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("hs", 0));
//      PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("hs", Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore")));
        highscore.text = "All time High Score: "+Mathf.Round (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("finalScore")).ToString ();
        text.text = "Final Score: " + Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore"));
        if(Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore"))<PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hs",0)){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("hs", Mathf.Round (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("finalScore")));
            highscore.text = "All time High Score: "+Mathf.Round (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("finalScore")).ToString ();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of whats happening:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

How is it even possible my high score went down!? 
Thank you soo much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
highscore.text = "All time High Score: "+Mathf.Round (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("finalScore")).ToString ();
```

You're using the "finalScore" value pulled from PlayerPrefs, not the "hs" value.

Addtionally, as AstroBoy points out in a comment below, your if-statement is backwards:

```
if(Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore")) < PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hs",0)){
```

You're only modifying "hs" when the final score is *less* than the high score.

I also don't know why you aren't using [`SetInt()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html) for a value you obviously treat like an integer.

Comment: I use setint because the z isn't always an int

Comment: Also, that is in the if statement, and it only runs when hs is less than finalScore. And hs is somehow always 0

Comment: @AstroBoyR It may not be, but you're always rounding it to an int, so at that point, its an int. You're also correct about the if-statement. I couldn't tease that out at first, as the code was pretty dense.

Comment: Ok, I can try today thanks. I'll let you know if it works!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are putting the wrong logic here, assuming `finalScore` is score obtained in that level and `hs` is  alltime high score

You wrote this line in **script 2**

```
(Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore"))<PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hs",0)
```

Change it to this

```
(Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore"))>PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hs",0)
```

> Note that Greater than symbol

Answer (score 2):

1. The problem is in you condition check.

Here you are checking if final score is less then highscore then you are setting it as highscore.

```
if(Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore"))<PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("hs",0))
```

Just inverse the condition and it will work

```
 if(Mathf.Round(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("finalScore")) > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("hs",0))
```

2. Also make sure you are using same float/int in both (setting and getting) high score.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `finalScore` PlayerPref to `int` instead of `float`. Sometimes Unity is funny when doing that kind of math. Ideally, try to keep the same type when they need to be compared or calculated.

You already convert it to `int` anyway, here:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("finalScore", Mathf.RoundToInt(FindObjectOfType<DistanceScore>().plrz));
```